# how to get field value in django admin form save_model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    player_achievement = models.ForeignKey(PlayerAchievement, related_name="guest_achievements")
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

I want to get the player selected in the form to use in my save_model method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        player = ??? how do i get this from the admin form?


        obj.player = player
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how you declared your form. If you inherited the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/), then you should in most cases use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) to select the associated `Player` with your `Guest` object and this is through calling `form.cleaned_data.get('player')`

Comment: This is an admin form.  I didn't create it.

Comment: Ok, I guess either `form.cleaned_data.get('player')` or `form.cleaned_data['player']` should still work

Comment: How can I keep it in a field.  ?

Comment: @egeogretmen thanks man that saved me a lot of trouble.